# PostgreSQL 9.2 Streaming Replication

Tags: postgresql, streaming, replication

Is there any way to Switchover the role of Master & Slave FREQUENTLY and synchronize Slave with Master and vice-verse?

Let see my network of machine goes off for 5 minutes on Master, then my Slave became the Master, but when my old Master network problem solved, then instead of building old Master with 'rsync' command, is there any possible way to synchronize old Master with only those changes made within 5 minutes?

Hoping for expert reply.

Answer (score 1):

i have been working on postgresql replication right now
you have not give proper description about your problem 
1) how you down the master killing postgres process or stop the master

there is no solution when master down using killing postgres except rsync because when master kill down master may have committed locally so there is inconsistency in data of master and slave due to master go ahead and slave left behind so next when old master try to came up as slave it will try to redo log at last checkpoint but it will not find that wal file from new master (old slave).

Comment: Sorry for the late reply.

I mean to say to 'recreate a old Master'?
Can I not use the datafiles on the former primary and just let it sync and get the incremental from the new primary? 

Most of the lolution showing tha to remove all the data files from the former primary and get all the datafiles through rsync (or other similar manner) from the new primary ? But I dont want to go with this loution, is there any alternate solution available?